# How do I get the data from this table on a website into a csv file?

Tags: html, csv, web-scraping

I am trying to get the data located on this website into a csv file. This code worked 2 weeks ago, but it returns "ValueError: No table found" when I run it now.

```
import pandas as pd
import html5lib
import datetime
now = datetime.datetime.now()
a=pd.read_html('https://www.comed.com/smart-energy/my-green-power-connection/developers-contractors/smaller-generators/interconnection-queue')
queue_pd=a[0]
```

Comment: If you're not stuck with Pandas, you could easily use visidata to browse any webpage for a table, and then save it to a CSV file

Comment: @CyrilChaboisseau I'm not familiar with visidata, how would that work?

Comment: Hello @user22062084 , download or use a packaged version of [visidata](https://www.visidata.org/install/), then open the webpage by calling 'visidata https://wikipedia.org/...' which will show you all the tables from that page, select one with return and save it with Ctrl+S